# Adding item in sharepoint 2013 default dropdown menu

Tags: sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to add new item button in a sharepoint 2013 dropdown menu?

[image]

I want to add item button in this Video and Audio dropdown

Answer (score 2):

use Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Media.Menu.Section.Controls._children". Here's the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOAcm.png). Example

```
<CustomAction
    Description="This Button will be used to choose Videos"
    Id="VideoPickerLinkRibbonAction"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
        <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition
                Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Media.Menu.Section.Controls._children">
                <Button
                  Id="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Media.Menu.CustomAssetPicker2"
                  Command="VideoPickerLinkRibbonCommand"
                  LabelText="From Sharepoint (your video action)"
                  TemplateAlias="o2"
                  Sequence="110"/>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIHandlers>
            <CommandUIHandler
              Command="VideoPickerLinkRibbonCommand"
              CommandAction="javascript:InitiateVideoPickerPopUp();" />
        </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```